# Firebase Google Sign-In Error

Tags: ios, firebase, google-signin

I have a Google Sign-In in my app using Firebase and I finished my app but when I run it the Gsignin button is acting as a regular button not as a Google Sign-In button. Here's a pic of my error messages that are coming in the console when run the app:

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".